# Managing Vim's 'tags' option when switching buffers

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm using [gem-ctags](https://github.com/tpope/gem-ctags) and [rbenv-ctags](https://github.com/tpope/rbenv-ctags) to index my gems and ruby libraries.

Also using a few plugins that affect where Vim looks for tag files:

- [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) (ruby standard library)
- [vim-bundler](https://github.com/tpope/vim-bundler) (gems)
- [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) (git repo)
- [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) (Rails project)

It's great being able to jump around a well-indexed code-base, but I'm finding that Vim's `'tags'` option is getting mishandled as I navigate the tag stack.

I'll start in a Rails project and find I can jump pretty much anywhere I want: within the app, into the ruby standard library (for the version of ruby relevant to the current project), or into a gem. So I jump into a gem, but then Vim can no longer find the tags for that gem, so I can't do any more easy navigation inside it.

*For example:* I have ruby 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 installed, and 2.2.0 is set as the global default.

Start Vim with an empty buffer from the root directory of a Rails app that uses ruby 2.1.0.

- Executing `:verbose set tags?` shows `'tags'` was last set by vim-rails.
- Tags are available within the app itself, in ruby's standard library (2.1.0), and in gems (also 2.1.0).

Open a file in the project.

- It now reports `'tags'` was last set by vim-fugitive.
- Same tag goodness as above. Fine so far.

Jump to a tag in a gem.

- Now `'tags'` was last set by vim-bundler, and it only includes the working directory, the current buffer's directory, and the ruby 2.2.0 standard library.

How can I make sure the tags file sitting in the root directory of whatever gem I'm navigating are found?

*NOTE*: I took inspiration from Tim Pope's [rbenv-sentience](https://github.com/tpope/rbenv-sentience) and added an appropriate .ruby-version file to the root of each ruby installation. `'tags'` still loses the gems paths when I navigate into a gem, but now it at least reflects the right version of the standard library. One step closer...

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Part of the answer was setting a .ruby-version local to each ruby installation. This ensured that whenever I was in a subdirectory of that installation (within an installed gem, for instance), it looked to the correct ruby installation's standard library.

The main fix, however seems to be searching recursively upwards from the current buffer or directory:

```
set tags-=./tags,tags
set tags+=./tags;~,tags;~
```

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017500/vim-difficulty-setting-up-ctags-source-in-subdirectories-dont-see-tags-file-i?rq=1), the semi-colon syntax allows you to search upwards until a designated "stop" directory (in my case `~`).

Actually, I probably only need to apply this change to the directory-of-current-buffer (`./tags;~`), since that'll cover 99% of my use cases.

It would also be nice if it could recognize the project's root directory and only search that far upwards, but I haven't found a way to accomplish that yet.