# ctags E426 and E433: how to resolve? (have checked out previous posts)

Tags: vim, ctags

I am not the first one to post this issue here:

[Vim: Difficulty setting up ctags. Source in subdirectories don't see tags file in project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017500/vim-difficulty-setting-up-ctags-source-in-subdirectories-dont-see-tags-file-i)

[What does a semicolon mean in the tags option](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11199/what-does-a-semicolon-mean-in-the-tags-option)

But I am running into the following errors:

```
E433: No tags file

E426: tag not found
```

in spite of following the solution suggested in the first link above, which suits my context better.

I have a root directory `/workspace/vinod` which has all the git repositories that I work with.

I have a simple script in this directory, to run the `ctags` command recursively on any chosen repository as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

CTAGS='ctags -R --tag-relative=yes --extra=+fq --verbose=yes'

read -rp "Enter repo: " repo

cd "$repo" || exit

eval "$CTAGS" || exit
```

After running this script for a chosen repo, I can see that the `tags` file is generated inside the top level directory of the repo (or repo root). The repo mostly has `.cpp` and `.h` files.

Now, I change directory to a sub-directory inside the repo, open a .cpp file and try to use `ctrl + ]` to go to the definition of a class, and that's when I hit the errors mentioned above.

I have tried this in multiple files within different sub-directories with the same result.

As recommended in the first link above, my `.vimrc` inside my home has the following:

```
set tags=tags;/
```

Can someone point out what am I missing here?

TIA

Comment: What is the output of `:echo tagfiles()` when editing that `.cpp` file?

Comment: Also, what does `:echo getcwd()` say?

Comment: BTW, there are at least four projects which supply "the `ctags` command" so this is not very descriptive. Did you check the content of the tags file to be correct and valid?

Comment: @romainl I tried :echo tagfiles() inside the file but it didn't give me any output. I repeated the same inside my .vimrc file with the same result.

Comment: @svlasov I tried :echo getcwd() inside the file and got no result. Also, did the same inside my .vimrc with similar effect.

Comment: @Friedrich my ctags is set to /usr/bin/ctags and I had installed it myself using yum. I am working inside my podman container on the corporate redhat 8 server, and this is the arrangement we have to isolate developer environments. If you noticed, I have verbose enabled in my ctags command, so yes I could see all the relevant files inside the repo parsed, and the output written to the tags file, which I opened to double-check that that was the case.

Comment: You are doing something wrong because those commands will always output something. You need to type them in VIM command prompt, don't put those to vimrc. At last, try running vim with `--clean` and repeat all the steps.

Comment: @svlasov I didn't say that I put the command inside my .vimrc; Rather, I tried running the command from the vim command prompt, once inside a source file in the repo, and failing to get any output, ran the same command using the command prompt inside my .vimrc, to see if being inside a repo made any difference, which obviously didn't.

Comment: @svlasov Instead of :echo getcwd() if I do :pwd I get the current working directory as the output.

Comment: @svlasov running vim --clean returns "Unknown option argument: --clean"

Comment: Could you add the full output of `$ vim --version` to the body of your post? It looks like an old Vim and/or one that is built without the required features. And FWIW, this is not how containers are supposed to be used at all.

Comment: For your edification see [Wikipedia on ctags variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags#Variants_of_ctags). Most likely you're using `universal-ctags` or the deprecated `exuberant-ctags`. Your package manager or `ctags --version` will tell you. Any ctags should produce compatible output *in theory*. Again: that's not the cause of your problems. If there's anything in the tags file, Vim should pick it up.

Comment: @romainl The vim version running on my container is 7.2 (2008 August 9, compiled Feb 17 2012 10:23:21). Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the full output here as I am running my container on a remote redhat linux box, and there is no option to copy to windows clipboard from there.

Comment: @Friedrich ctags --version gives me Exuberant Ctags 5.8 Compiled Jan 4, 2010, 07:52:03

Comment: Consider moving to more recent software. Vim 7.2 was released 15 years ago. You should also make the clipboard work. For now, do `vim --version > version.txt` and copy that file. You can copy files from your remote? Even back than, tags worked. None of these explain your problems but your setup looks just a little bit outdated.

Comment: Old Vim hypothesis confirmed.

Comment: I tried running ctags on a similar configuration (a linux box) but without the container...the Vim and ctags versions that came with the Redhat distribution were exactly identical...this time, it worked although I had to disable cscope by using set nocst in my .vimrc...this leads me to think that the issue is related to the container envrionment